# JArray into Object with Attributes

Tags: c#, json

I need to convert the following JArray into an Object.
My problem is, that i need to do this with Attributes.
Because i'm not able to change the following call in a decoupled class:

```
var message = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(e.Message, messageType)
```

The JSON

```
[71,[[77372266,1508067366000,-0.12144759,5517.4],[77372265,1508067366000,-0.020001,5518.2],[77372251,1508067362000,-0.01,5517.2],[77372235,1508067358000,0.020001,5517.8],[77372220,1508067352000,-0.41883579,5517.3],[77372218,1508067352000,-1.05740887,5517.2],[77372211,1508067351000,-1.8084,5517.2],[77372207,1508067350000,-0.01565918,5517.2],[77372206,1508067349000,-0.01721768,5514.3],[77372205,1508067349000,-0.10347625,5514.3],[77372201,1508067348000,-1.08183286,5513.1],[77372200,1508067348000,-0.04218858,5513.1],[77372199,1508067348000,-0.020001,5513.3],[77372198,1508067348000,-0.020001,5513.3],[77372197,1508067348000,-0.020001,5513.3],[77372196,1508067348000,-0.020001,5513.3],[77372195,1508067348000,-2.16396207,5513.3],[77372194,1508067348000,-1.5601,5513.5],[77372193,1508067348000,-0.13520397,5514.2],[77372192,1508067347000,-0.01479603,5514.2],[77372191,1508067347000,-0.13659854,5513.4],[77372189,1508067346000,-0.01597635,5513.3],[77372187,1508067346000,-0.19812221,5513.3],[77372184,1508067346000,-0.01261482,5513.3],[77372183,1508067346000,0.131033,5519.7],[77372182,1508067346000,0.2011,5519.4],[77372181,1508067346000,0.074337,5518.2],[77372180,1508067346000,0.125,5517.5],[77372179,1508067346000,0.06401,5516.5],[77372178,1508067346000,0.05305,5516.3]]]
```

My Classes

```
public class Root 
{
    public int ChannelId { get; set; }

    public List<Item> Data { get; set; }

}

public class Item
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public long Timestamp { get; set; }

    public decimal Price { get; set; }
    public decimal Size { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Isn't there a json format for your input?

Comment: I have reformated the sample. The Json is above the classes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use the [Newtonsoft JSON library](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json) (nowadays referred to as JSON.NET) you can use the [`Jsonconverter` class](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonConverter.htm) to create your own custom converter.

Your class would then look something like:

```
 public class MyCustomConverter : JsonConverter
    {
        public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
        {
            return typeof(Root).GetTypeInfo().IsAssignableFrom(objectType.GetTypeInfo());
        }

        public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
        {
            if (reader.TokenType == JsonToken.StartArray)
            {
                JArray rootToken = JArray.Load(reader);

                if (rootToken[0] != null && rootToken[1] != null)
                {
                    var root = new Root(rootToken[0].Value<int>(), this.readItems(rootToken[1]));
                    return root;
                }
            }

            return existingValue;
        }

        private IList<Item> readItems(JToken items)
        {
            var itemList = new List<Item>();
            if (items.Type == JTokenType.Array)
            {
                foreach(var item in items.Children())
                {
                    if (item.Type == JTokenType.Array && item.Count() == 4)
                    {
                        itemList.Add(new Item(
                            item[0].Value<int>(),
                            item[1].Value<long>(),
                            item[2].Value<decimal>(),
                            item[3].Value<decimal>()));
                    }
                }
            }

            return itemList;
        }

        public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
```

Note that this custom converter in the current state is only capable of transforming JSON to an object, if you want it to be able to transform a `Root` object to a JSON string you need to implement the `WriteJson` method yourself.

You said that because of a decoupled dependency you cannot change the way the callee calls the deserialize method. What you can do is overwrite the [JSONConvert.DefaultSettings](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/DefaultSettings.htm) property and tell it explicitly to use the custom converter.

```
        JsonConvert.DefaultSettings = (() =>
        {
            var settings = new JsonSerializerSettings();
            settings.Converters.Add(new MyCustomConverter());   
            return settings;
        });

        var jsonString = "...";
        var root = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(jsonString, typeof(Root));
```

Answer (score 1):

First parse your json to JArray and then you can simply create a function to parse it into an object of your choice. You can try this:

```
string json = "[71,[[77372266,1508067366000,-0.12144759,5517.4],[77372265,1508067366000,-0.020001,5518.2],[77372251,1508067362000,-0.01,5517.2],[77372235,1508067358000,0.020001,5517.8],[77372220,1508067352000,-0.41883579,5517.3],[77372218,1508067352000,-1.05740887,5517.2],[77372211,1508067351000,-1.8084,5517.2],[77372207,1508067350000,-0.01565918,5517.2],[77372206,1508067349000,-0.01721768,5514.3],[77372205,1508067349000,-0.10347625,5514.3],[77372201,1508067348000,-1.08183286,5513.1],[77372200,1508067348000,-0.04218858,5513.1],[77372199,1508067348000,-0.020001,5513.3],[77372198,1508067348000,-0.020001,5513.3],[77372197,1508067348000,-0.020001,5513.3],[77372196,1508067348000,-0.020001,5513.3],[77372195,1508067348000,-2.16396207,5513.3],[77372194,1508067348000,-1.5601,5513.5],[77372193,1508067348000,-0.13520397,5514.2],[77372192,1508067347000,-0.01479603,5514.2],[77372191,1508067347000,-0.13659854,5513.4],[77372189,1508067346000,-0.01597635,5513.3],[77372187,1508067346000,-0.19812221,5513.3],[77372184,1508067346000,-0.01261482,5513.3],[77372183,1508067346000,0.131033,5519.7],[77372182,1508067346000,0.2011,5519.4],[77372181,1508067346000,0.074337,5518.2],[77372180,1508067346000,0.125,5517.5],[77372179,1508067346000,0.06401,5516.5],[77372178,1508067346000,0.05305,5516.3]]]";

var array = JArray.Parse(json);

var channelId = array[0];
var listData = array[1].ToList();

Root root = new Root();
root.ChannelId = Convert.ToInt32(channelId);
root.Data = new List<Item>();
for (int i = 0; i < listData.Count; i++)
{
    Item newItem = new Item();
    var item = listData[i].ToList();

    newItem.Id = Convert.ToInt32(item[0]);
    newItem.Timestamp = Convert.ToInt64(item[1]);
    newItem.Price = Convert.ToDecimal(item[2]);
    newItem.Size = Convert.ToDecimal(item[3]);
    root.Data.Add(newItem);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, but as described above, i need to use Attributes because i can not change the deserialization call.